# Not able to SSH to instance2 from Instance1 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel7

I have launched two AWS RHEL7 instances in US East and West regions . I'm not able to ssh to instance2 from instance1 [using private ip]

In the security groups , I have added SSH rule for both the instances.

```
ssh: connect to host 172.X.X.X port 22: No route to host
```

I'm using Putty to connect to those instances as my local OS is Windows .

Comment: @Rudiger - Now i used elastic ip to ssh , i.e ssh user@elatsticip and it worked . but not with ssh user@privateip . Not sure why !! . But I have allowed all the ip's through 22 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two instances are in different regions, they will not be able to connect to each other by default. They are isolated. AWS does not provide any way for you to directly link two networks in two different regions using private IPs.

Comment: Well ; But i could ssh using ElP's but not with private IP's .  Can you please educate me ? As i'm new to AWS .

Comment: If you wish to SSH between private IPs, those IPs need to have a route to each other, and a security group allowing access. You can do this using a single VPC in one region.

Comment: If you wish to SSH between private IPs, those IPs need to have a route to each other, and a security group allowing access. You can do this using a single VPC in one region, or two VPCs in one region using a VPC Peering connection. If you want to use two regions, map an EIP to each instance and create a security group allowing the EIP for one instance to SSH to the EIP on the other instance.